# Fastest way to check if a always changing set of strings contains a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, comparison, hashset

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Take a string
2. Check if HashSet contains the string
3. If it doesn't, add the string to the HashSet (if it does, do something else)

This must work with a very large arrays of strings the fastest way possible

Is using HashSet the fastest way to check if string already has occured or is there something better for .net 4.5?

Comment: Yes the generic types are the fastest way !
so you are using a HashSet which is a generic type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [HashSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx)

> returns **true** if the element is added to the HashSet object; **false** if the element is already present.

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();
bool b1 = hs.Add("xxx"); //returns true
bool b2 = hs.Add("xxx"); //returns false
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `HashSet<T>(IEqualityComparer<T>)` should be used for strings.

Comment: @m-y Why do you think it is needed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx -- StringComparer should be used instead of the default comparer. Also, it explicitely states in code the developers intention on whether this is case-sensative/culture-sensative. It's not required, but just a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using the new Concurrent Data Types speed up your program, but use a profiler to compare the scenarios and choose the best option.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/26/9997562.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

[Help with C#.NET generic collections performance and optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522737/help-with-c-net-generic-collections-performance-and-optimization)